You’re a couple of real winners?

You’re a couple of real winners. I mean, we don’t hoard what we have.
Room in the car—fine. But then to sit right back and give us this crap
while my brother has to deliver laundry, well, it just makes you
wonder.

It is an excerpt from the novel Fat City by Leonard Gardner.
Two women pick up a man on the side of a highway. Because the back seat is full of stuff, this man has to sit on the front seat next to the these women. On the way, the driver changes her mind and makes the man get out of the car. At first, he resists, but finally, he has no choice and gets out of the car. These sentences mentioned above are what the driver says.
Is the first sentence sarcastic? Does the driver say it to that man and her friend that sat next to each other and the driver somehow envies them?
And about the second and third sentence, does she mean " however we are not stingy ,but the room in the car is another thing and we don't want to share it with you anymore."?

Wikipedia's synopsis says Munger continues to fight and, hitchhiking home from a fight in Salt Lake City alone, he is picked up by two young women who eject him from the car on a stretch of highway in the dark of night after an awkward exchange revealing Munger's lustful longing.  So she means that she's fine with giving him a lift, but not happy about his offensive conversation. The comment appears to be sarcastic, but I don't know why it's addressed to two people. Had the other woman encouraged him?

@KateBunting thank you .The author doesn't explain things clearly. This is his writing style. He describes events vaguely and lets the reader discover the truth. Munger, when he pretends he is asleep, touches the neck of another woman with his face, and I think the woman isn't reluctant. However, she doesn't show any sign, but she doesn't object either. So I think the driver feels what is happening and criticize both of them and refer to his brother work that is hard but he doesn't ask for any favors and indirectly addresses that boy who said he was there for business but he hitchhikes home.

Yes, it's sarcastic.

Currently you can read the full context here. Obviously the first sentence is sarcastic. I haven't bothered to read the entirety of the preceding conversation, but it seems like the driver (female, apparently unnamed) is getting fed up with how her friend Noreen and the hitchhiker are interacting. So they are the two "winners" ("You two are a couple of real losers" in more direct speech). Note that earlier, the driver says to her companion "Oh, 'come off it. You've had your ass pampered since the day you were born".
